# How do I configure Sublime Text 2 to automatically use user-built build system for fortran?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Here is my `/Packages/User/Fortran.sublime-build` file's contents.

```
{
    "cmd": ["gfortran", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.f, source.f90, source.f77, source.f95",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell": true,
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have [this](https://github.com/textmate/fortran.tmbundle) extracted in `/Packages/Fortran/`.

How do I configure Sublime Text 2 so that it automatically chooses this build system for all fortran files without having to manually change the build system?

Answer (score 0):

As long you've added the above build system to your project (where you have used the appropriate selector), you should be fine. Just make sure that Tools -> Build System -> Automatic is selected.